# Problem Attaching internal file to GMail in my android app

Tags: android

My app writes data to text files (on sd card and internal memory).
Later the app emails the text files to a list of people.
I am having trouble getting gmail to attach a file that is pulled from the internal application files area. 'Native Android mail' can attach a file from either internal or SD card area with no problem. Gmail will attach a file if it's from SD card, but won't attach a file if its located in internal storage.

// this sends a file from SD - works for android mail and gmail

```
Intent jj=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String fileName = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/aFolder/externalfile.txt"           

jj.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileName));
jj.setType("text/plain");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(jj , "Select Sender");
startActivity(chooser);
```

// this sends an internal file-works for android mail, but no attachment sent with gmail

```
Intent jj=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String fileName = "file://" + getFilesDir().toString() + "/internalfile.txt";

jj.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileName));
jj.setType("text/plain");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(jj , "Select Sender");
startActivity(chooser);
```

Any suggestions?
Do I need to give Gmail special permission somehow?
My attachments are all text files - written by the app.
Internal files were created with openFileOutput(myFile,32769)

Thanks
John D

Comment: Gmail intents doesn't allow to send(put in attachment)files from internal storage. So you have to use external memory only :(

Comment: pankaj - Can you point to any documentation that confirms that?

Comment: I get the following message in logcat:      ERROR/Gmail(9147): file:// attachment paths must point to file:///mnt/sdcard. Ignoring attachment file:///data/data/my.package.name/files/myfile.txt      How should I interpret this?  
- Can I NEVER attach an internal memory file to a GMail?  
- Do I need to change permissions?  
- Do I need to construct my URI in different way?

Comment: same problem. I can't attach files to Gmail, however using other email client I can.

Answer (score 2):

the only way I found around this was to make my own content provider and pass in the uri to my content provider as the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dhego, I used a content provider. Specifically, a FileProvider.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Using this only requires that you modify your Manifest and create an additional resource file. Also, you will need to obtain a validly formatted URI via a static method provided by FileProvider.

In your Manfiest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.authority.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
     </provider>
```

The "com.example.authority.fileprovider" is your application authority with "fileprovider" appended.

In the res/xml folder, create a file_paths.xml file that contains the paths to the files you want to expose. In my case, I was exposing them from the application cache directory, so my XML looks like:

```
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <cache-path name="reports" path="reports/"/>
    </paths>
```

In my case, "reports" is a folder within the application cache directory that I am writing files to.

The last thing to do is in your code:

1. Write files you want to expose to the folders and storage areas specified in file_paths.xml.
2. Generate a valid URI to set on the Intent you will invoke for sending an email (Intent.ACTION_SEND).

Here's some sample code:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.example.authority.fileprovider", fileToAttach));
```

Invoke startActivity on your Intent and that should be it!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is indeed [an issue with gmail](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18872). Unfortunately however, at the time of the writing it seems it hasn't been fixed.