# Sending GMail with attachment from Android app

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem Attaching internal file to GMail in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762073/problem-attaching-internal-file-to-gmail-in-my-android-app)

My app writes data to text files on internal memory.
Later the app emails the text files to a list of people.

If the user selects GMail to send the mail and attachment, the mail goes, but attachment does not.

I get the following message in logcat:

> ERROR/Gmail(9147): file:// attachment paths must point to file:///mnt/sdcard. Ignoring attachment file:///data/data/my.package.name/files/myfile.txt

How should I interpret this?
 - Can I NEVER attach an internal memory file to a GMail?
 - Do I need to change permissions?
 - Do I need to construct my URI in different way?

Here's the code snippet that created the EXTRA_STREAM:

```
String filename = "file://" + getFilesDir().toString() + "/myile.txt";  
myintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filename));
```

BTW this works fine with built-in Android mail. It just fails on GMail.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762073/problem-attaching-internal-file-to-gmail-in-my-android-app

Comment: I am working on same problem as an earlier post. This post adds and focuses on the logcat message. JD