# Android: Is it possible to share a string as text file through an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, text, share, android-contentprovider

There are a lot of tutorials on how to save strings to text files, and how to share text files via an intent ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581132/how-to-send-text-file-by-using-intent-in-android) an example of the latter).

But what if I want to skip the middleman and not have my string saved to the filesystem? Is there any way to provide a string as a text file through an intent without actually saving it to the filesystem? Like through a stream or something? To clarify, I don't want it provided as just text; I want the receiving app to think it's actually a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing really easy for that. `EXTRA_STREAM` takes a `content` `Uri`. You would have to create your own `ContentProvider` that handled `openFile()` and transferred your string over via a `ParcelFileDescriptor`-based pipe.

[This provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v9.0/ContentProvider/Pipe/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/pipe/PipeProvider.java) demonstrates the technique. In my case, I am reading in an asset and streaming it out; in your case, you would just stream your string (presumably as UTF-8 encoded bytes).